# Tab android application

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs

I'm on an application that has  3 tabs, 
I put inside the `onCreate()` functions for each tabActivity a toast that shows a text, well
when I press the tab it shows me the toast, when I press tab again it doesn't show me!

so, my question Does `onCreate()` run for one time ? if yes 
how can I update anything inside it like ListView contents and so on..

I'm new to android...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes onCreate runs only once.

Normally you'd update your code by user interaction or a thread running in the background.

If you want to do something everytime you click a tab you need to make a listener that listens to tab interaction from the user. Alternatively you could use the onResume() or onStart() methodes (these will also be called in other situations though). For more info look at [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).